# Construct new table by dropping rows that don't have highest "priority"

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains a list of names used to designate objects (represented themselves by an `id`). It is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE all_names
(
    id       integer NOT NULL,
    name     varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    priority integer NOT NULL,
);
```

(The `priority` field is mostly used to sort the list of synonyms of an object with given `id`.)

I would like to create from this table another table that associates to each object its name with highest priority. Columns should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE objs
(
    id       integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name     varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

);
```

How can I fill the new table with only the top names?

**Example**

*all_names:*

```
id name priority
----------------
1  A    3
1  AA   2
1  AAA  1

2  B    1

3  C    4
3  CC   3
3  CCC  2
3  CCCC 1
```

should give me:

*objs:*

```
id name
-------
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

as the name of object `1` with highest priority is `A`, etc.

**EDIT**

[Fiddle that also includes proposed solutions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=627914a355c49b9ef69fbac081c97ada)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! In future, could you please include (as applicable) fiddels (dbfiddle.uk) with your questions - it reduces duplication of effort and also provides a single source of truth - help us to help you! You might want to consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=627914a355c49b9ef69fbac081c97ada) when implementing your desired solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `distinct on` like below

```
insert into objs
select distinct on (id) id,name 
from all_names 
order by id, priority desc
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=908b10cdc945347154240801d75d6369)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, name, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority DESC) rn
              FROM all_names )
INSERT INTO objs (id, name) 
SELECT id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```